# .Net Key based caching. Touching dependant models

Tags: .net, caching, basecamp

From http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works

"You deal with dependency structures by tying the model objects together on updates. So if you change a todo that belongs to a todolist that belongs to a project, you update the updated_at timestamp on every part of the chain, which will automatically then update the cache keys based on these objects."

I am learning about key based caching and trying to implement in .Net. This is the one point I am struggling with, updating cache items which are dependant on a recently update cache item.

```
    class Parent
    {
      public int ID;
      public DateTime updated_at;
      public Child child;
    }
    class Child
    {
      public int ID;
      public DateTime updated_at;
      public string name;
    }
```

Say I add `Child` to the cache. Then create `Parent` using that `Child` and cached that too. When I update the `Child` I want to bust the cache for the `Parent` in the same manner that 37Signals has.

The only way I can see is by updating the `updated_at` flag on the `Parent` at the same time I am on the `Child`. I am not sure though and would love some clarification.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You should show how you are constructing keys.
The mentioned article is tight to memcached, thus some features of memcached mentioned would need to be implemented when you would use this method.

Comment: What features are they? Is it the "belongs_to" and "touch" stuff?

Comment: Garbage collection on the cache is the most evident one. In .NET there is no real limit to cache size and no automatic removal in case of an overrun.

Comment: I will be using the Azure Caching with sliding expiration which solves that issue.